# Taking the 'product' of lists

Tags: python, list

Suppose that I am given a list of strings, e.g. `list = ['a', 'b', 'c']`. I am also given a list of 'continuation strings', e.g. `continuations = ['d', 'f']`, and I want to form a list of all possible sequences formed by combining the original list with a continuation letter. In this example, I want to obtain the list of lists: `new_list = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'f']]`. To do this, I tried

```
new_list = []
for element in continuations:
    # Make a copy of the original list
    copy = list
    # Add a continuation letter to the original list
    possible_sequence = copy.append(element)
    # Add the new list to the list of lists
    new_list.append(possible_sequence)
```

But this generates `[None, None]`... Can anyone explain what is wrong with my code?

Comment: use zip to iterate in parallel

Comment: @9769953 the idea of `list.append()` is to make a new list that combines the old list `['a', 'b', 'c']` with each continuation letter.

Comment: @9769953 When I write `list.append('d')`, I get the new list `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`.

Comment: @9769953 sure, that's why I made a copy of the list (see second block of code). Do you have any idea why it doesn't work? I have tried debugging it, but without gaining any insight

Comment: @9769953 I didn't say that it ran, and haven't edited it (that would have made the question very confusing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

1. create a list to store the possible sequences
2. iterate through the continuation list
3. copy the original list
4. append the continuation letter to the copied list
5. append the copied list to the possible list

```
def combine_list(list_, cont_list):
    # create a list to store the possible sequences
    possible_list = []
    # iterate through the continuation list
    for j in cont_list:
        # copy the original list
        l2 = list_.copy()
        # append the continuation letter to the copied list
        l2.append(j)
        # append the copied list to the possible list
        possible_list.append(l2)
    return possible_list

l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
c = ['d', 'f']
print(combine_list(l, c))
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'f']]
```

## Edit

---

What's wrong with your code?

1. If you want to copy a list you need to it with `list.copy()`. If you just do `copy = list` you are not creating a new list object. if you make changes in `copy` all changes will apply to `list` also.
2. The `list.append(element)` function does not return a list object it returns `None` that's why your result looks like this `[None, None]` you appended `None` twice.

Comment: Great, thanks for this. But do you have an idea what is wrong with my second block of code? I really don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: @afreelunch you need to create a new list object by copying it with `copy()` if you do `copy=list` it is not creating a new list if you make changes in `copy` all changes will apply to `list` also

Comment: perfect, thanks for explaining that! It finally all makes sense...

Comment: @afreelunch the `.append(element)` function does not return a list it returns `None` that's why your result is `[None, None]`. You appended `None` twice

Comment: @noath1400 I don't think that is an issue. If you take my code and do the copying properly (e.g. with `copy = list.copy()`), then the code runs fine

Comment: @afreelunch if you only change the copying proccess your code still returns `[None, None]`

Comment: Yes, I see that you are right actually!

Answer (score 2):

**CODE**

```
main_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
continuations = ['d', 'f']

new_list = []
for element in continuations:
    temp_list = main_list.copy()
    temp_list.append(element)
    new_list.append(temp_list)

print(new_list)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'f']]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
# it is a bad practice to shadows built-in name, so I changed 'list' name to 'abc_list'
abc_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
continuation = ['d', 'f']
print([abc_list + [x] for x in continuation])
```

Output: `[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'f']]`

Answer (score 1):

In Python, `append` modifies the list it is called on and doesn't return anything (technically it returns `None`, which is why you ended up with a list full of `None`). That means that you cannot store the result of `append` in a variable.

```
my_list = []
foo = my_list.append(1)
print(foo)        # Prints 'None' because that's all that append returns
print(my_list)    # Prints '[1]' because the value got added to the original list by append
```

This is the big difference between lists and strings in Python that beginners sometimes get confused about. Strings are immutable which means they cannot be changed. So methods such as `replace` return a new string, because they cannot modify the original string. Lists, on the other hand, are mutable, meaning they can be modified. So methods on lists such as `append` or `pop` modify the list they are called on rather than returning a new one.

```
my_string = "Python"

# Needs to be stored in a new variable,
# the original string cannot be modified
new_string = my_string.replace("n", "k")

print(my_string)    # Still the original value, Python
print(new_string)   # The new modified value, Pythok

my_list = [1, 2]
my_list.append(3)   # Modified the list itself, no need to store anything new
print(my_list)      # [1, 2, 3]
```

Also, note that it is an extremely bad idea to call one of your lists `list` as `list` is a keyword in Python. (It is used to construct new lists, e.g. `list(range(10))` creates a list `[0, 1, ..., 9]`).